# Problemas con el comando ng para crear un proyecto

Tags: javascript, angular, cli

El problemas es que recién instalo angular, no tuve problemas, la instalación fue correcta, pero cuando quiero hacer un nuevo proyecto con "ng new" no lo reconoce.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A mi me ha pasado eso, cuando abro una consola, después instalo, y en esa misma consonla que ya estaba abierta antes de ng sea parte de los comandos intento correr un comando ng.
Lo que pasa es que abres una consola cuando ng no es un comando valido, instalas angular cli, y sin cerrar esa consola donde ng no es compando valido quieres utilizarlo, falta el paso de cerrar y volver abrir consola.. No se si sea tu caso, pero así me ha pasado a mi.

Answer (score 0):

¿si haces `ng --version` qué te aparece?, además, puedes intentar cerrando y abriendo la consola a ver si funciona.

En todo caso, puedes usar:

```
npx -p @angular/cli ng new aprendiendo-angular
```

Y de esa manera no tienes que instalar nada.

Comment: "ng" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: Eso es porque no esta instalado el CLI de angular, instala con npm install -g @angular/cli, o  con el comando de la respuesta